# UI thread freezes

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am creating a new thread using the following function.

```
public void toCallAsynchronous() {
    mThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // do something here
                    if(mLoggedIn)
                    {
                        boolean syncresult = mDownload.syncData();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "local Thread sleeping");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    //mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
```

I am calling this in onResume as I want this thread to start only when user has login into his account. The synData function accesses the server for new files, downloads them and update entry into a database. Could you please identify what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` is strange because you, probably, don't want this thread to run forever. At the very least it should be `while(!isFinishing())`

Also you will want make sure `mDownload.syncData` doesn't try to access any UI, if it does there will be an exception.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I changed it to while(mRunning) setting it to true in onResume and setting it false in onPause and onDestroy. Also there was some UI action on syncData which after removing it ran perfectly.